# queryselector only happen once on text element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling understanding some basics concept I guess,

I have this JavaScript function which take a dom element and should increase it's number every time the button is clicked, the thing is, the number increase once and never increase again, console.log show the actual number but not the stPage element. From my understanding it has to deal with the DOM element stored, so I have to kill the first child, I think I did so, but it doesn't seems to work.

If some can help me, please do, thank you really much <3

```
function stpage(){

   //Setting child element + simple increment function
    let numberNode = document.getElementById('stPage');        
    let articleNumber = 0;
    articleNumber++;

    //killing the child then display the element on the page
    numberNode.removeChild(numberNode.childNodes[0]);
    document.querySelector('#stPage').innerHTML = articleNumber;

};
```

Edit: `articleNumber` has to be outside the function scope.

```
let articleNumber = 0;

function stpage(){

    articleNumber++;
    document.querySelector('#stPage').innerHTML = articleNumber;

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-initializing `articleNumber` to 0 every time the function is called on this line:

```
let articleNumber = 0;
```

It should be something like:

```
let articleNumber = 0; // outside function scope, doesn't reset

function stpage() {
  let numberNode = document.getElementById('stPage'); 
  articleNumber++;
  numberNode.innerHTML = articleNumber;
};
```

Comment: Wow was that simple henn... I declared articleNumber outside the function.  thank you really much, it's working now